# Calculating different values and forming a table in XML?

Tags: android, xml

I want to create an application in which I will be using a 'for' loop...by doing so I want to save each value that I am calculating and want to display them in a tabular form in XML...I have problem in the last part...I cant seem to find a solution on how to send those calculated values to XML in a tabular form?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to manually create the xml String yourself using a StringBuilder.

I can't be too specific since your question is so vague, but something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append("<parent>\n");
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  sb.append("<child>" + (i * 3.1415) + "</child>\n");
}
sb.append("</parent>");
```

That should leave you with something like:

```
<parent>
<child>0</child>
<child>3.1415</child>
<child>6.283</child>
.
.
.
</parent>
```

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.coopersoft.solarpv&hl=en
Please go to this link, check app screenshots, I am willing to make tables just like the ones shown their...all the values will be calculated in the backend..and displayed like this on a table...help me with this...plz